# Problems installing TortoiseSVN 1.6.12 on Windows XP

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-xp

I installed TortoiseSVN 1.6.12 for Windows XP SP1 but it's not working. As far as I know when I right-click on any folder a *Checkout* option should be available inside the context menu, but I don't see anything. I already restarted my PC several times but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have SP3 installed? This would allow you to install the latest version 1.7.6 of TortoiseSVN.

Check at *Control Panel > Software* if it's really installed correctly.

Also make sure you installed the correct version. It seems there are differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit version:

http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#nomenus

Comment: This certainly looks much better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Check Sebastian's 32/64-bit hypothesis first. It looks much more plausible.

Does 'Tortoise SVN' item appear in the right-click menu? If 'yes': go to *Start -> All Programs -> Tortoise SVN -> Settings -> General -> Context Menu*. See if it has appropriate boxes checked.

If 'no' - do you have *Tortoise SVN* in *Start -> All Programs*? If not - Tortoise simply did not install. If 'yes' - then you need to dig further.

Comment: She already mentioned that the context menu item doesn't appear.

Comment: @Sebastian, she only mentions that *svn checkout* does not appear. Although it does seem that words 'dont see anything' mean that nothing Tortoise-related appears, my experience answering questions here taught me not to assume anything not explicitly stated :)

Comment: @Scot: You're right. Never assume anything not explicitly stated. I should know it better. :-)